# 行ごとに列の数が異なる CSV から、特定の値を取り出したい

Tags: python, pandas, csv

形が整っていないcsvから特定の値を取り出したい。（行と列を指定して）
以下のようなcsvがあり、pandasを用いてデータを取り出そうとするとエラーが当然出てきます。

実現したいことは、

- 4行3列の値を取り出す
- 17行3列の値を取り出す

のような操作をできるようにしたいのです。

**対象のCSV:**

```
SetupTitle, 0_NMOS_id-vg_vg-0.5-1_step2m_vd0.1_vb0-1_vsub0
PrimitiveTest, I/V Sweep
TestParameter, Context.MainFrame, B1500A
TestParameter, Channel.UnitType, SMU, SMU, SMU, SMU, SMU
TestParameter, Channel.Unit, SMU1:HR, SMU2:MP, SMU3:MP, SMU4:MP, SMU5:MP
TestParameter, Channel.IName, ID, IG, IS, IB, Isub
TestParameter, Channel.VName, VD, VG, VS, VB, Vsub
TestParameter, Channel.Mode, V, V, V, V, V
TestParameter, Channel.Func, CONST, VAR1, CONST, VAR2, CONST
TestParameter, Channel.Index,
```

追記

ご回答頂いたことを基に、プログラムを実行させて頂きましたが、
エラーが出力され、うまく動かせません。
また、元のcsvには、1行目は空欄となっています。
空欄はミスではなく空欄があることが正しいです。

実行コード

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_names, names=list("abcdefg))
```

エラー

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c9fb50f13326> in <module>
      1 # df = pd.read_csv(file_names, skiprows=18,names=list["asdfghj"])
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv(file_names, names=list("abcdefg"))
      3 
      4 # df = df.drop('DataName', axis=1)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    686     )
    687 
--> 688     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    689 
    690 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    435     # See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1297
    436     fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
--> 437         filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
    438     )
    439     kwds["compression"] = compression

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    241     if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer):
    242         msg = f"Invalid file path or buffer object type: {type(filepath_or_buffer)}"
--> 243         raise ValueError(msg)
    244 
    245     return filepath_or_buffer, None, compression, False

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Comment: `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>` と表示されていますので、`file_names` がリストになっているのでしょう。

Comment: `pandas.read_csv()` ではデフォルトで空行を無視します(`skip_blank_lines=True`)。

Comment: 追記に関して：出来たDataFrameにも最初の行に空欄が含まれて欲しいということですか？ またカンマの後に空白1文字が有りますが、これも有効なデータに含まれるということでしょうか？ そうした条件の場合、CSVに存在しない位置のデータはどんな値にしたいのでしょう？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらの記事の回答を応用すれば、CSVデータ内容に応じたDataFrameを取得出来るでしょう。
[Pandas read_csv expects wrong number of columns, with ragged csv file の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41734794/9014308)

ヘッダー行の有無とかを調整するなら、それに応じた処理を追加する必要がありますが。
こんな感じになります。

```
import pandas as pd

def ragged_csv(filename):
    f=open(filename)
    max_n=0
    for line in f.readlines():
        words = len(line.split(','))  #### 区切り文字は , に戻す
        if words > max_n:
            max_n=words
    lines=pd.read_csv(filename,sep=',',names=range(max_n))  #### 上記に同じ
    return lines

df = ragged_csv('data.csv')
df.fillna('', inplace=True) #### 必要ならば、存在しなかったデータ(NaN)を空文字列に変更
```

出来たDataFrameからは、@payaneco さん回答のようにデータを取得出来るでしょう。

---

その後、`csv`モジュールで読み込んでからpandasでDataFrameにすれば同様のことが少し簡単に出来るのを見つけました。色々組み合わせて約2行で出来ますね。
[csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)
[PythonでCSVファイルを読み込み・書き込み（入力・出力）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-csv-reader-writer/)
[Convert jagged array to Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63496104/9014308)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv', newline='') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame([row for row in csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]).dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True).fillna('')
```

- `, ID, IG, IS, IB, Isub`とかのカンマ後の空白1文字を無効にするなら、`, skipinitialspace=True`を残し、有効にするなら削る。
- CSVファイル内で1行まるまるデータが無い部分を削除するなら、`.dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)`を残し、有効にするなら削る。
- CSVファイルで行内にデータが無い部分の値を空文字列にするなら`.fillna('')`を残し、`None`のままで良いなら`.fillna('')`を削り、何か別の値にしたいなら`.fillna('')`の`()`内に指定する。

Answer (score 1):

事前にカラム数の最大値を取得しておく方法も考えられます。

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f:
  ncol = max(len(r) for r in csv.reader(f))
  f.seek(0)
  df = pd.read_csv(
         f, names=range(ncol), header=None, na_filter=False,
         converters={c: str.strip for c in range(ncol)},
         skip_blank_lines=False)

print(df)
print(f'4行3列の値 = {df.iloc[3, 2]}')

# 出力結果(入力したCSVファイルの1行目は空行)
                0                                               1  ...        5        6
0                                                                  ...                  
1      SetupTitle  0_NMOS_id-vg_vg-0.5-1_step2m_vd0.1_vb0-1_vsub0  ...                  
2   PrimitiveTest                                       I/V Sweep  ...                  
3   TestParameter                               Context.MainFrame  ...                  
4   TestParameter                                Channel.UnitType  ...      SMU      SMU
5   TestParameter                                    Channel.Unit  ...  SMU4:MP  SMU5:MP
6   TestParameter                                   Channel.IName  ...       IB     Isub
7   TestParameter                                   Channel.VName  ...       VB     Vsub
8   TestParameter                                    Channel.Mode  ...        V        V
9   TestParameter                                    Channel.Func  ...     VAR2    CONST
10  TestParameter                                   Channel.Index  ...                  

[11 rows x 7 columns]
4行3列の値 = B1500A
```

`pandas.read_csv()` で `na_filter=False` を指定すると欠損カラムには空文字列(`''`)が挿入されます。

Answer (score 0):

csvの情報をいったん行データとして読み込み、それをカンマ区切りで分割する方法でも対応可能です。
[SO本家の類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55188544)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
# 4行3列の値を取り出す
value = df.iloc[3][2]
print(value) # "SMU"が返る
```